# Bordered UITextView

Tags: ios, quartz-core

I want to have a thin gray border around a `UITextView`. I have gone through the Apple documentation but couldn't find any property there. Please help.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

....

// typically inside of the -(void) viewDidLoad method
self.yourUITextView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
self.yourUITextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: I didn't think it really needed much explaining, view is the UITextView, and the code goes wherever you'd set up the view (awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad are two possible places).  Since there was no code given there's no way to give good context in response.

Comment: XCode don't let me to set border for layer. It says that layer is read-only. I made UIView (where put some elements) and trying to set border to that view. Trying to do this `self.myView.layer.borderWidth ...`, but as I said, layer is read-only, so layer don't have any methods or variables to set

Comment: Did you import QuartzCore?  You could also try getting out a CALayer from self.myView and setting borderWidth on that.  It's settable.

Comment: Some more information on "layer" being read-only in UIView (the layer property is, but you can set values in the layer for a view): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837077/isnt-property-layer-of-uiview-be-readonly

Answer (score 44):

Add the following for rounded corners:

```
self.yourUITextview.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Answer (score 27):

Here's the code I used, to add a border around my `TextView` control named "tbComments" :

```
self.tbComments.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
self.tbComments.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.tbComments.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

Easy peasy.

Answer (score 19):

I add `UIImageView` as a subview of the `UITextView`. This matches the native border on a `UITextField`, including the gradient from top to bottom:

[image]

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *borderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height)];
borderView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UIImage *textFieldImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TextField.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 8, 15, 8)];
borderView.image = textFieldImage;
[textField addSubview: borderView];
[textField sendSubviewToBack: borderView];
```

These are the png images I use, and a jpg representation:

[@1x](http://www.wikiupload.com/IYBTAYNHPGCSL6U)

[@2x](http://www.wikiupload.com/13INPF5F7UAP96A)

[image]

Comment: Good solution. Are these images yours? Are we free to use them?

Comment: These images are 'modeled' on those used in Apple's own apps. In truth I extracted them and made very few, if any, changes. Use at your own risk. The goal was to mimic the native look and feel so it is hard to come up with something that looks much different. For what it's worth, I have shipped and had approved apps using this image without issue.

Comment: The png image files appear to have been removed - I don't intend to constantly update this with a new image location so my apologies if the jpg doesn't work for you. I can re-upload as and when requested via comment.

Comment: With the image attached this works best:
`code` resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(28, 14, 28, 14)

Comment: The WikiUpload links (for the two images) fails to find the image files now.  ;-(

Answer (score 18):

Works great, but the color should be a `CGColor`, not `UIColor`:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: #import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 8):

I believe the above answers are for the previous versions of Swift. I Googled a bit and the below code works for Swift 4. Just sharing it for whoever it may benefit.

```
self.textViewName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
self.textViewName.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
self.textViewName.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: With Swift5 and the dark mode you can even use the system colors: `self.textViewName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor`

Answer (score 4):

for Swift Programming, use this

```
tv_comment.layer.borderWidth = 2
tv_comment.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

Comment: Or just `UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1).CGColor`

Answer (score 3):

this is as close as I could from an original UITextField

```
func updateBodyTextViewUI() {
    let borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 212/255, green: 212/255, blue: 212/255, alpha: 0.5)

    self.bodyTextView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    self.bodyTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    self.bodyTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add border to UITextView from the Storyboard - Identity Inspector - User Defined Runtime Attribute

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8 and Xcode 6, I now find the best solution is to subclass UITextView and mark the subclass as an IB_DESIGNABLE, which will allow you to view the border in storyboard.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface BorderTextView : UITextView

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "BorderTextView.h"

@implementation BorderTextView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
}

@end
```

Then just drag out your UITextView in storyboard and set its class to BorderTextView

Answer (score 0):

The thing that made it work (in addition to following the answers here) is adding the `borderStyle` attribute:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
..

phoneTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
phoneTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
phoneTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition. If you make the border a bit wider, it will interfere with the left and right side of text. To avoid that, I added the following line:

```
self.someTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, you may use the following two lines:

```
myText.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

myText.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be to insert a real UITextField on the bottom and prevent it to scroll with the content. This way you have even the correct dark mode borders.

```
class BorderedTextView: UITextView {

  let textField = UITextField()

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    insertTextField()
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    insertTextField()
  }

  convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: .zero, textContainer: nil)
  }

  private func insertTextField() {
    delegate = self
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    insertSubview(textField, at: 0)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textField.frame = bounds
  }
}

extension BorderedTextView: UITextViewDelegate {

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    textField.frame = bounds
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the UITextView show the borders when the view controller containing the UITextView is presented? It's not showing up for me, even if I set the values of UITextView layer.borderColor to UIColor.black.CGColor and layer.borderWidth to 1.0 in viewWillAppear().

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem in storyboard by putting a fully disabled `UIButton` behind the `UITextView` and making the background color of the `UITextView` clearColor.  This works without requiring extra code or packages.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't work in iOS 7, as the buttons have no edges  (the buttons look like labels now)