# UIColor for UITextView border

Tags: uitextview, border, uicolor, cgcolor

According to this answer:

[Bordered UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647164/927822)

I can use premixed colors like blackColor, blueColor etc...

I want to use my own color though, made from UIColor colorWithRed: ...

```
ratingText.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:33 green:95 blue:139 alpha:1] CGColor];
```

The border then is not displayed. How could I bridge the UIColor to CGColor, or do I miss anything else?

Help is greatly appreciated - thx!

Answer (score 0):

`[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]` takes float value from 0 to 1. Values greater than 1 will consider as 1. Therefore this will result in white color.

You should first convert the rgb value(0-255) to float value(0-1) first by dividing 255.

```
layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:33/255.0f green:95/255.0f blue:139/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor];
```