# UITextView text border

Tags: iphone, text, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Border around UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647164/border-around-uitextview)

I want to create a border around the text in a UITextView. I was able to accomplish this by creating 8 separate UITextViews and offsetting them to the 8 pixels around the center text. This looks really nice, but inputting text is severely slowed since the view has to update 9 transparent UITextViews simultaneously every time the user types something!

Is there a cleaner/faster way of accomplishing this? The effect I want is similar to photoshops 'stroke' modifier.

Comment: You ***really*** created 8 text views? o.O

Comment: Ya lol, I had no other way to do it at the time!!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you put screenshot of what u mean by border around the text ?

If you want to have the border for UITextView try out following, this should work

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100)];
    textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why my answer was deleted, perhaps because I posted the same solution on an almost identical question? You can find it there:
[Bordered UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647164/border-around-uitextview)

Comment: your solution is not right for this question. he needs border around the text of textview, not around frame of textview