# Isn't property layer of UIView be readonly?

Tags: iphone, ios, transform, layer

The property layer of UIView is described in Apple's doc as following:

**layer**

The view’s Core Animation layer used for rendering. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) CALayer *layer
```

It is obviously that it is readonly. But in my project, why it could be set as following:

```
NSLog(@"before: %f",self.myView.laye.frame.size.width);
[self.myView.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)];
NSLog(@"after: %f",self.myView.laye.frame.size.width);
//log shows us that the frame is modified
```

Really confused in this situation. Anyone can help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `layer` property is read-only, it means you cannot change the layer for another, however the `CALayer` object contained in the property is not immutable, you can set its own properties.

You cannot do:

```
self.myView.layer = newLayer;
// equivalent to [self.myView setLayer:newLayer];
```

But you can do:

```
[self.myView.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)];
```

It's the `setLayer:` selector that you can't use.

Answer (score 1):

[CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) is not part of UIKit. It’s part of the Quartz Core framework

while [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) class  is a part of UIKit. You can read the documentation of both to know the differences

UIView inherits from NSObject and CALayer also inherits from NSObject so at the time you are  doing: [self.myView.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)];

You are not assigning the layer , you are actually accessing the [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class layer properties directly and therefore you can play with position, size, and transformation of a layer, as you can see in [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation, it allows all these things

Comment: Quartzcore is a core level framework, but UIkit is build as a higher level framework for IOS only, so therefore using Quartzcore CALayer you can access the properties of layer of a view. still any doubts my friend ?