# How to set the border of UITextView to same as border color of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

By default `UITextField` has a light gray color as its border color.
I want to set my `UITextView` to have the same border color as the `UITextField`.

I tried:

```
myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
// or
myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightTextColor().CGColor
// or 
myTextView.layer.borderColor = myTextField.layer.borderColor
```

They still have up to have different color.

How to set the `UITextView` border to match `UITextField` color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bordered UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647164/bordered-uitextview)

Comment: I want to set border color to bottom line. How to do it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this code.

```
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

myTextView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

change borderWidth and cornerRadius value to get exact ui as UITextField.

Comment: In Mac there is a utility called DigitalColor Meter. Use that utility to get the exact RGB of textfield. you just need to drag your cursor over the UITextField border.

Comment: I used a border width of .5 to get the exact look of another entry on my screen for the iPad mini.

Comment: @caitlin agreed, the default border width is not 1.

Answer (score 32):

This Swift code also works for setting same border color, width & radius as `UITextField`:

```
myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: Shouldn't the color components be 0.8?

Answer (score 17):

I had this similar question for iOS 10, and wasn't able to find an answer, but this is what I found using the Digital Color Meter in Utilities and the iOS Simulator.

***Swift 3 / iOS 10***

```
let color = UIColor(red: 186/255, green: 186/255, blue: 186/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
myTextView.layer.borderColor = color
myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: i didn't even know that there is such app on mac :)

Answer (score 7):

swift 4.x/ios11.

I did another measure in PSD using simulator.
I can confirm radius is 0.5 and color is 0.8, as 205/255 = 0.8 (or "cdcdcd" in HEX, as PSD suggests, BUT width must be **0.5**.
(I attached a PSD where You can compare radius of edit field (UITExtField) AND radius applied to a UITextView.

So its correct:

```
    let borderGray = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)
    self.TxtV.layer.borderColor = borderGray.cgColor
    self.TxtV.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.TxtV.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Note: I tried to get color from a TextField already on View, but I got:

if let borderGray = self.cellPhoneTxt.layer.borderColor{
        let BG = UIColor(cgColor: borderGray)

```
    print(BG)
    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    BG.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
    print(red, green, blue, alpha)

}
```

but I got in console:

kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1

0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0

so it seems Apple is using full black AND some Alpha.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this code for Swift

```
let borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor.Cgcolor()

myTextView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

Comment: This makes it white.

Answer (score 4):

## As with Swift 5.2 and with dark mode support :)

I only wanted to add an example with semantic UI using adaptable colors. Sometimes hardcoding the values is not what you want especially if you support dark mode.
I think using `.label` as semantic color gets you to the default gray used by the UITextField border in light and dark mode.
Try this out:

```swift
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.label.cgColor
```

I like to play with other semantic colors too. This will look nice in dark mode:

```
myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
```

and your UITextView will look exactly the same with:

```
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
```

Comment: I think the question here is more: "What are the actual text field values?"

Comment: Do you mean the RGB values? There was already an answer with RGB values but I wanted to use the semantic colors instead.

Answer (score 2):

The exact color is:

Objective-C:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.76 green:0.76 blue:0.76 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

Swift:

```
UIColor(red:0.76, green:0.76, blue:0.76, alpha:1.0).CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

For generic solution through out the project. You can extern UIView class and add these methods to it.

```
-(void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor{
    self.layer.borderColor = (borderColor).CGColor;
}
-(UIColor*)borderColor{
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor: self.layer.borderColor];
}

//Getter and setter for border width
-(void)setBorderWidth:(NSInteger)borderWidth{
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}
-(NSInteger)borderWidth{
    return  (NSInteger)roundf((self.layer.borderWidth));
}
```

[Its](https://github.com/KoderLabs/UIView-Designable) an extension to UIView. Just add these UIView+Designable.h/m files in your project and you can see the multiple more options in attribute inspector.