# What is the UITextField default borderColor in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a button with a border that I want to style as a UITextField.

So I tried:

```
self.dateButton.layer.borderColor = self.assesseeName.layer.borderColor
```

But that gives me a black border:
[image]

How do I get the same color as the UITextField (top of screenshot)?

Comment: Usually I take a punt and use `[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.08]` and then adjust as necessary.

Comment: It's answered already here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/25966955/5546312](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25966955/5546312)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to apply same effect of textfield to buttton (borderwidth, bordercolor, & corner radius)

```
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

dateButton.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;   
dateButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
dateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

Comment: The color you have given does not match the default uitextfield border color

Comment: @oyahi : i just given color for demo purpose u can take anything that u want. by default is gray color for textfield border.

Comment: The question specifically asks for "How do I get the same color as the UITextField (top of screenshot)?" So I was expecting your answer to have the same color.

Comment: U can use replaced first line for color :

UIColor *bordercolor = [UIColor cyanColor]; 

and remaining code as it its.

Comment: You can changes the color as u want or u can use haxstring also

Answer (score 30):

I set the border color for the button to be the standard light gray and the border width to be 0.25 and that matched

Swift 3:

```
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

Comment: on iOS 11 borderWidth is 0.5 (not 0.25) I believe.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Mac's Digital Color Meter the RGB of the borders is 230, 230, 230.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 13 the color changes between light and dark mode

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(dynamicProvider: { trait in
        if trait.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            return UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.2)
        } else {
            return UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
        }
    }).cgColor
} else {

    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Answer**

*Textfield default border color is gray.*

```
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
let borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 204.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
uitextfield.borderColor = borderColor
uitextfield.borderWidth = 0.5
uitextfield.cornerRadius = 5
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in Swift 5.

```
let borderColour = UIColor(red:204.0/255.0, green:204.0/255.0, blue:204.0/255.0, alpha:0.4)
dateButton.layer.borderColor = borderColour.cgColor
dateButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
dateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```