# Why does the border of UITextView not show when layer.borderColor & layer.borderWidth properties are assigned values saved in variables?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Why is the border of UITextView shows when I set the value of layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth properties with literals, but does not show when I set the value of those properties with the values of variables?

The following code saves the values of UITextView layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textViewBodyBorderColor = self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor

    print("self.textViewBodyBorderColor: \(self.textViewBodyBorderColor)")

    self.textViewBodyBorderWidth = self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth

    print("self.textViewBodyBorderWidth: \(self.textViewBodyBorderWidth)")

}
```

This is the result in the debug window.

> self.textViewBodyBorderColor: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
> self.textViewBodyBorderWidth: Optional(1.0)

The following code sets the values of the respective properties of UITextView with the values of the variables that was assigned those respective values in UIViewController.viewDidLoad().

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    print("self.textViewBodyBorderColor: \(self.textViewBodyBorderColor)\n\tself.textViewBodyBorderWidth: \(self.textViewBodyBorderWidth!)")

    self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor = self.textViewBodyBorderColor!
    self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth = self.textViewBodyBorderWidth!

    print("self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor: \(self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor)\n\tself.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth: \(self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth)")

}
```

> self.textViewBodyBorderColor: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
> self.textViewBodyBorderWidth: 1.0
> self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
> self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth: 1.0

When I set the values of layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth in viewWillAppear(animated:) with literals as in the following code, such as the following, then textViewBody shows a border.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    print("self.textViewBodyBorderColor: \(self.textViewBodyBorderColor)\n\tself.textViewBodyBorderWidth: \(self.textViewBodyBorderWidth!)")

    self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    print("self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor: \(self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor)\n\tself.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth: \(self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth)")

}
```

These are the results in the debug window:

> self.textViewBodyBorderColor: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
> self.textViewBodyBorderWidth: 1.0
> self.textViewBody.layer.borderColor: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
> self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth: 1.0

Update with additional information I didn't mention before:

I set the initial values of those properties in Identity Inspector under the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" heading by putting "layer.borderColor" and "layer.borderWidth" in the Key Path column, and Number and Color as the respective types under the Type column, and 1 and black in the Value column. I learned how to do that from this [answer to question "Bordered View"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647164/bordered-uitextview/61986472#61986472).

Comment: By default, a `UITextView` has a clear `.layer.borderColor` and 0.0 `.layer.borderWidth`. Where are you initially setting them to non-default values?

Comment: @DonMag In viewWillAppear(animated:) as in the code above the second code segment that shows what is in viewDidAppear. I set them to UIColor.black.cgColor and 1.0. It works when I set those two values in a UIAlertAction() which I select after the UIViewController is up and running, which is basically after viewWillAppear has executed.

Comment: @DonMag I just changed to code to set the borderColor to UIColor.green.cgColor and the borderWidth to 7.0 in viewWillAppear and it works. The UITextView shows those values.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... in `viewDidLoad()` you are setting your vars: `self.textViewBodyBorderWidth = self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth` ... but at that point, `self.textViewBody.layer.borderWidth` is **Zero**

Comment: @DonMag Sorry. I didn't say that I set the layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth properties in Identity Inspector->User Defined Runtime Attributes in Xcode.

Comment: @DonMag Here is where I learned to set those properties in Identity Inspector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647164/bordered-uitextview. The link goes to the question, not the answer. I don't know how to get the link to the answer.

Comment: @DonMag Here is the answer that showed me to use the Identity Inspector to set those properties of UITextView. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647164/bordered-uitextview/61986472#61986472. I figured out how to find the exact address to the answer, not just the question.

Comment: You **can** set the `layer.borderWidth` in User Defined Runtime Attributes. You ***CANNOT*** set the color, as there is no option for `CGColor`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set border width and color via User Defined Runtime Attributes, you *can* do it like this:

[image]

Then, in code, you'll need to get that color and change it to a `CGColor`:

```
@IBOutlet var textViewBody: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let c = textViewBody.value(forKeyPath: "layer.borderColor") as? UIColor {
        textViewBody.layer.borderColor = c.cgColor
    }
}
```

You don't need to do that with `.borderWidth` because the attribute set in Storyboard / IB is a valid value.